# #! in url not working in billdesk payment gateway integration in Java

Tags: angularjs, payment-gateway

I am using `billdesk` payment gateway integration.The problem i am facing is the `#!` symbol in the url, If i send the request as

```
 https://pgi.billdesk.com/pgidsk/PGIMerchantPayment?msg=PONDIUALUM|DIS1521C|NA|1|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|R|pondiualum|NA|NA|F|90|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|http://35.132.116.138/#!/getDonationDetails|73392E6982AC5ECFAF073079D4F82B1DC1EA89E6550E95693F861B12F91ACE07
```

It is not working.It is showing as Invalid Merchant Details..But if i remove `#!` before getDonationDetails then it is working and redirecting to payment page.But the problem if i remove `#!` is after payment response is not redirecting to `getDonationDetails` method inside `35.132.116.138.So` is there any way around so that i can remove `#!` but still be able to redirect the response after payment to `getDonationDetails` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own url has prefix in the config phase of AngularJs like this:

```
ngModule.config(($locationProvider) => {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
});
```

I hope, this is what you are looking for.